# Getting a substring delimited by multiple characters in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

First off, I know a variation of this question has been asked many times but I've found no answers anywhere online for the following.

I have a table of forenames. Some of the names are double barreled i.e. Mary-Jane, Barbara Ann. I need to get a substring of the names, extracting just the first part of the name, i.e. Mary, Barbara.

The problem is that in the table, some are split using spaces ( ) and some are split using dashes (-).

This is the query I have currently:

```
SELECT forename, LEFT(forename, charindex(' ', forename) - 0) changedName
from student
```

The first argument of charindex can be a space or a dash, both work fine but I need a way to run the query that will remove both dashes *and* spaces.

All names must be in the one column.

Using MSSQLS 2014.

What is the best way to so this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple method:

```
SELECT forename,
       LEFT(forename, patindex('%[ -]%', forename) - 1) as changedName
FROM student;
```

If some students have single names (neither character), you can do:

```
SELECT forename,
       LEFT(forename, patindex('%[ -]%', forename + '-') - 1) as changedName
FROM student;
```